# Unzip content of specific folder on Solaris

Tags: solaris, zip

I try to unzip the content of a specific folder of a zip file. My zip file structure looks like:

- folder1

  - folder1_1
  - file1_1
- folder2
- folder3
- file1
- file2

I want to unzip only the **content** of folder1.

I tried to using:

```
unzip -d path_to_unzip/ results.zip 'folder1/*'
```

Unfortunately it creates a structure like:

path_to_unzip/folder1/folder_1_1
etc...

How can I archieve to get rid of the unnecessary folder1?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't look like Info-ZIP has any way of stripping directory prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I archieve to get rid of the unnecessary folder1?

As Ignacio correctly pointed out, `unzip` cannot.

I would propose something like this:

```
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d` || exit 1
unzip -d ${TMPDIR}/ results.zip 'folder1/*'
mv ${TMPDIR}/folder1/* path_to_unzip/
rm -r ${TMPDIR}
```

Basically, since `mv` file operations on a single filesystem are atomic, as in, performed "almost" immediately, there is no real performance impact ... provided your `/tmp` is on the same filesystem as the destination path. If it is not and the ZIP file is of great size, you should extract it to a temporary folder on the target filesystem. Here, we take the parent of the target directory:

```
TMPDIR=`mktemp -p path_to_unzip/.. -d` || exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution! Is it possible to archive this with
    tar?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of, neither Solaris `tar` nor GNU `tar` can do what you want.

Comment: GNU `tar` has `--strip-components`.

Comment: Learned something new today, you can also use `--transform=SED_EXPRESSION` nice!